# Java - ResultSet change Db column names to show in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I am using **rs2xml**.jar for populating data into table. here is my code of showing table columns and data

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from employees");

table_employees.setModel(DBUtiles.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

This code successfully works But I want to rename the columns. I don't want to show the DB Columns in my table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the `TableColumn` from the `TableColumnModel`:

```
TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();
tcm.getColumn(0).setHeaderValue("whatever you want");
```

Or you can override the `getColumnName(...)` method when you create your JTable:

```
JTable table = new JTable( DBUtilities.resultSetToTableModel(rs)
{
    private String[] columnNames = 
    {
        "Column 1",
        "Column 2",
        "Column ..."
    };

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int col) 
    {
        return columnNames[col];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using the code below if you wish to use DB values with java column names and you can set the column names in java using the TableModel property of the jTable.

```
DefaultTableModel tmodel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
tmodel.addRow(new Object[] {....});
jTable1.setModel(tmodel);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can get column name as per your choice from Sql query like

```
SELECT column name as 'Student Id', Column Name as 'Student name' FROM student;
```

Query give you result with column name as per you decide.