# Java JTable - show rows only which matches the string

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowsorter

I have a `JTable` populated with data from a database. I have added a search function that display the rows, if word matched to some rows when the data is typed into a `JTextField`. But at the minute as you type a string or word that do not matches any of the rows data, what I want to do is to hide all the rows, and the `JTable` will show just the column names. Just like when something matches IT, shows those rows only which has the string that user typed and hide others.

Here is my code that I am using:

```
               if (text.length() == 0) {
                 sorter.setRowFilter(null);
               } else {
                 try {
                   sorter.setRowFilter(
                       RowFilter.regexFilter(text));
                 } catch (PatternSyntaxException pse) {
                   System.err.println("Bad regex pattern");
                 }
               }
             }
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24218546/131872 for a simple solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use a `DocumentListener`, along with the row filter. You can see how to [Write a DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html).

Basically the listener listens for changes in the underlying document of the text field. From the methods you override in the `DocumentListener`, you can get the text, like you're currently doing, and set the regex ex filter like you're currently doing

Here's simple example (disregard the applet. I just got the boilerplate code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325722/how-can-i-perform-a-case-insensitive-filter-on-a-jtable) and added the document listener). Note: that same post has an answer provided that will allow you to filter in a case-insensitive way, if you're looking for that functionality

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.RowFilter;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;

public class TestTableSorterFilter extends JApplet {

    private String[] columnNames
            = {"Country", "Capital", "Population in Millions", "Democracy"};

    private Object[][] data = {
        {"USA", "Washington DC", 280, true},
        {"Canada", "Ottawa", 32, true},
        {"United Kingdom", "London", 60, true},
        {"Germany", "Berlin", 83, true},
        {"France", "Paris", 60, true},
        {"Norway", "Oslo", 4.5, true},
        {"India", "New Delhi", 1046, true}
    };

    private JTable jTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);

    private TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter
            = new TableRowSorter<>(jTable.getModel());

    private JTextField jtfFilter = new JTextField();
    private JButton jbtFilter = new JButton("Filter");

    public TestTableSorterFilter() {
        jTable.setRowSorter(rowSorter);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(new JLabel("Specify a word to match:"),
                BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel.add(jtfFilter, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(new JScrollPane(jTable), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jtfFilter.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener(){

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {}

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                String text = jtfFilter.getText();

                if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(text));
                }   
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent arg0) {
                String text = jtfFilter.getText();
                if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
                } else {
                    rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(text));
                }   
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but I think that it should be [rowFilter = RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + filterText);](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14102764/714968), where "(?i)" make case insensitive, accepts uppercase and lovercase chars same ways

Comment: @mKorbel I posted the link from the question I asked, that shows how to do that :)

Comment: hmmm good catch, because sometimes I leaving to read desciptions

Comment: Or you can look at the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) which has a working example that does exactly this along with explanations.