# Issue after filtering a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm having some problems related to my Java project.

I am using a `JTable` and a `JTextField` used to filter the rows of the table, and here's my problem:
if I write something in this `textfield` the table appositely filters the results, but when I delete all the text in this `textfield` there is one last character after the `""` string that is invisible.
If I use `textfield.setText("")` the `textfield` actually isn't empty at all and it doesn't allow to refresh my table with the old rows.

In other words I need to set the `textfield` with `""` string, so it can update\refresh the `JTable` with the ordinary rows (without any filter applied).

Is there any method or listener that can solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

You should be using a [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) which listens for changes in the underlying document of the test field.

But it sounds like your problem is that you are not doing a check before setting the filter. If there is no text, you should set the filter to null.

```
    if (text.trim().length() == 0) { // or if (text.isEmpty())
        rowSorter.setRowFilter(null);
    } else {
        rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(text));
    }
```

See full example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24228290/2587435)

Also see more explanation at [How to Use Tables: Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

Comment: Thanks, I solved using a Document Listener as you said. I also used Document Listener before too, but I associated it to a wrong event (KeyPressed)